# I Need Help Getting Contacts from Broken Android!

Tags: contacts, backup, data-recovery, broken-screen

My Huawei Mercury M886 fell out of my lap when getting out of the car and it got run over...

Its not rooted. The screen is completely shattered off and I cant use the touchscreen or buttons so I cant get passed the lock screen.

I was able to get about half my contacts from my back up in April on the wireless server from Cricket, and I don't use the Gmail back up and purposely did it that way. I plugged my phone into the computer but I cant access the phone at all since I have to choose the USB/Computer option from the phone itself.

Anyone know of how I can get to them? They are not on the SD card either. I need a way to access the phone without using the touchscreen. Is there a way to sync the Android phone to PC without using the touchscreen?

I don't have my phone password protected. It seems as though that the Android can do everything except retrieve information without using the touch screen...this is a HUGE problem...very impracticable for bad situations.

Comment: If your phone's logic board is still intact: [Here's](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1411603) a way to get it mounted on linux (it's a rooting procedure but would allow you to pull all your data from it too). Another method: Buy a used Mercury off ebay and fix yours with it. And some tips for the future: Don't have a single point of failure. Do backups or use the cloud. Your phone may also be stolen (etc.) and then you have nothing left to recover data from.

Comment: I forgot: You need Linux ([any Live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_live_CDs#Linux-based) will work, or just take Knoppix) and follow from step 5 onwards (5. Holding the Vol+ AND Vol- AND Power together when the phone is off will put the phone into a mode that gives you a BRIGHT purple screen....

6. Start linux and plug the phone in. You'll have full r/w access to your phone. Make a copy.
7. Unplug the phone from USB.

Comment: @TheAndroNerd Why? `adb install` some VNC or the like, or trigger the right intent to export the data, or copy the database into some Android Emulator and use the contacts app there to export... Once rooted, the possibilities are many. And even if, it wouldn't be that complicated.

Comment: Does your phone supports USB OTG? If it can, then simply plugging a mouse will let you control the screen. From there do a contact export or titatium backup from the phone.

Comment: I think your phone supports USB OTG according to this [site](http://www.cellularfactory.com/det.jsp?d=53040&c=778898). Try to buy one and plug a USB mouse. This is way easier than doing the steps above.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get your contacts back, for a number of reasons:

- You would have to have been rooted [AND]
- You would have to have USB Debugging enabled [AND]
- You would have to individually go through the contacts app database, and get the contact data. They aren't stored in vcard format.

Comment: There's always a way. It only boils down to the question: How much is it worth it. (I.e. maybe it's worth it to pay an expensic forensic expert to get lost company data back). See my comment after the question itself.

Comment: @ce4 Maybe you quote a little from the book you're currently reading? Andrew mentioned something on this, as far as I remember. Your link in above comment probably is one of the possibilities ;)

Comment: Hehe. Just found it via google.