# How to get your data(Photo's/Video's) from your broken phone?

Tags: hardware, photos, restore, samsung

Last week my Samsung Galaxy Fame broke, everything still works only the screen doesn't work anymore. It won't react if you touch it but it still works when you unlock it, so basically you can't do anything. Does anyone know how to restore my photo's to my PC, when I plug it into my computer it shows me that there aren't any files, but I have done it before and there should be files. Can anyone PLEASE HELP ME?!

THANKS A BUNCH

Comment: There are several [related questions with answers](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=backup+broken+screen+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) you might want to check, e.g. [Backup apps on SGS 2 with broken display?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/51629/16575) and [I Need Help Getting Contacts from Broken Android!](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/34444/16575). Though they're not explicitly about photos/videos, they certainly hold useful hints for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The Galaxy Fame has a micro SD card and by default photos and videos are saved there. Just plugin the card to any PC via a reader and you should have the photos and videos.