# Retrieving contacts from Nexus 4 with broken screen

Tags: contacts, adb, nexus-4, broken-screen

My Nexus 4 is recognized by `./adb devices` when connected via USB. Also USB debugging is enabled. Unfortunately the device isn't rooted so pulling the contacts db file doesn't work as I don't have access to the appropriate directories (I think). How can I retrieve my contacts in this situation?

Note I never synced my contacts with Google.

Comment: Please take a look at similar questions: [I Need Help Getting Contacts from Broken Android!](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/34444/16575) / [How do I backup data (SMS/contacts) from a device with a broken screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25646/16575) Both of them have answers which might solve your issue as well. If not, please [edit] your question and let us know how your situation is different, so we can find another way to help you.

Answer (score 1):

if you got airdroid working you can use your pc screen.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid

you can get the app installed through google play online.

is your screen broken meaning you cant see it, or it also doesnt accept input?

Comment: Thanks for the info. My screen was broken and would not respond to touch events. However the display still works. The solution I went w/ was issuing adb commands to open the contacts app, scroll up/down, view contact etc and just wrote down the info for each contact.